# codeigniter flashdata not clearing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a newbie to codeigniter and I'm creating a project in which users are created and managed. here I'm using flashdata to display the temporary messages like "user created",etc.,

My code to set flash data is

```
       $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'User Created.');
```

In my view I called it as

```
$this->session->flashdata('message');
```

My problem is that when the user is created,flashdata is displayed and when i click home link the flash data is still available but when i click refresh/home again it disappears. I want it to be cleared when i click the home link for the first time itself. Is there a way to code it??.

Comment: Flashdata is cleared every time the application is accessed. You don't happen to have any ajax shennanigans hanging off your home button?

Comment: Thanks guys ... I didnt expect such a response... really excited.. I am going to dive so much deeper into php so that this site is here....feeling great...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Flashdata will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.**

```
if($user_created)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User created!');
    redirect('login');
}
else
{
    redirect('register');
}
```

Comment: This did it for me. Was having the same issue. Was loading the view instead of redirecting. Still was able to pass values i.e. error messages to the redirect

Comment: It may the version of php

Answer (score 3):

if you want to clear set_flash in **controller** or **another view file**, then you can use this simple code.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User not found...'); //create set_flash
```

**unset** set_flash

```
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); die; //for check 

if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The flashdata is supposed to display once.

And it gets disappears on page refresh.

So, if you redirect the page to another, it should work.

If you do not refresh the page, you can do it through jQuery.

Say your div displaying flash:

```
<div id="flash-messages">Success Message</div>
```

Write jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#flash-messages").click(function(){$(this).hide()});
});
</script>
```

Comment: using jquery can i set any time intervals to make it hide like hide(time_interval)??.. Is it right

Comment: thanks ...sorry to ask this ... But how to set it b'coz I'm not good in jquery and all...

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() {
         $("#flash-messages").hide());
    }, 5000);
});

Answer (score 1):

You should `redirect` after `user created`. Then when `next time` you click on `home link` it will not appear, try this,

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'User Created.'); 
redirect(base_url().'home.php');// you can change accordingly
```

Answer (score 1):

You **must redirect** the page somewhere **after** `$this->session->set_flash('item','value');`

*Example*:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error',validation_errors());
    redirect(base_url().'user/login');
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Thank you');
    redirect(base_url().'user/login');
}
```

Usually developer make a mistake when they submit data to same page. They set flash data but forget to redirect.

Comment: Even when i redirect, the flash message does not disappear. PLease help.
I redirect to same page

 {

   
   $this->Crud_model->insert_dept($deptdata);
   $this->session->set_flashdata('dept_created', 'Department has been created..!');
   redirect(base_url() . 'Forget/settings');

   //redirect(base_url() . 'Forget/settings');
  }else{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('dept_not_created', 'Department has not been created..!');
   redirect(base_url() . 'Forget/settings');

  }

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Ajax framework for automatically  hide the flash message.Also their contains all of the flash operation.

You can get more information from here.
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Ajax-Framework-For-CodeIgniter

Comment: While this is a solution, I don't think it directly answers the users question with the issue of loading views vs redirects.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, just extend the Session library and add a clear_flashdata function.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

// application/libraries/Session/MY_Session.php
class MY_Session extends CI_Session
{

    public function __construct(array $params = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($params);
    }


    /**
     * Clear flashdata
     *
     * Legacy CI_Session compatibility method
     *
     * @param   mixed   $data   Session data key or an associative array
     * @return  void
     */
    public function clear_flashdata($data)
    {
        $this->set_userdata($data, null);
    }
}
```